# How to get correct number of buttons in a matrix?

Tags: cocoa, xcode4

Xcode 4.6. 
I need to put 5 radio buttons in 2 columns, 3 in the first column and two in the second. I don't have enough real estate to put them in one column. If i select 2 columns, I get an even number of buttons. I'm sure I'm missing something really simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show how you populate your cells, but you just need to add a *blank cell* in the last position:

```
NSCell *blankCell = [[NSCell alloc] init];
blankCell.enabled = NO;
[_matrixView putCell:blankCell atRow:row column:column];
```

Comment: I create them at design time with Xcode. With your code, I either get no buttons at all, or all the original buttons. Must I create all the buttons in code to be able to do what I want?

Comment: @Mike Yeah I think you must; I've only ever created the buttons programmatically so I get the correct number.

Comment: After playing with it a bit, you can use it for an IDE created matrix. You have to give the blankCell a blank title.